# touchesMoved don't work for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I want to create sliding UIToolbar by touching the UIBarButtonItem on it and moving. I read some topics, and found that I must implement touchesMoved. But where? Only place that I found it's UIButton which I located in UIBarButtonItem.

This is viewController **viewDidLoad**

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.size.height - 2.5*height, bounds.size.width, 2*height)];

SlideButton* infoButton = [SlideButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
UIBarButtonItem *slideButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infoButton];

self.toolbar.items = items;
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
```

Most strange in this, that I tried to bind UIButton to action (addTarget:action:forEvents)
And it's works, very exact. But I can't take position of touch, because I have no event that occured, so I can't use this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your toolbar.

It recognize only pan gestures(drag). In target method check if touch is in frame of you bar button with `CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect, point)` method and first touch  like `if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)`.

if yes then enable dragging after `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded or
   UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`
disable dragging.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about this method of recognize.